# Python group a range of percentage with increment and count the number of group

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 groups of lists which are A1, A2, A3 as in group A, B1, B2, B3 in group B, 
and C1, C2, C3 in group C.

```
a1 = ["ID_A1", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'C']]
a2 = ["ID_A2", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T']]
a3 = ["ID_A3", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'G']]

b1 = ["ID_B1", ['C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'C']]
b2 = ["ID_B2", ['C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C']]
b3 = ["ID_B3", ['C', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C']]

c1 = ["ID_C1", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T']]
c2 = ["ID_C2", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T']]
c3 = ["ID_C3", ['T', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'G']]

data_set = [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]
```

I have already compared their similarities with the codes below:

```
def compare(_from, _to):
    similarity = 0
    length = len(_from)
    if len(_from) != len(_to):
        raise Exception("Cannot be compared due to different length.")
    for i in range(length):
        if _from[i] == _to[i]:
            similarity += 1
    return similarity / length * 100

result = list()

for entry1 in data_set:
    for entry2 in data_set:
        percentage = compare(entry1[1], entry2[1])
        print("Compare ", entry1[0], " to ", entry2[0], "Percentage :", round(percentage, 2))
        result.append(round(percentage, 2))
print(result)
```

Instead of sorting all the similarities into a group according to their own value of similarities, I want it to be grouped like in a range of 95% to 96% with an increment 0.1, depends on how user want to input the range. I want it to have 0.1 increment because i have really big data but I cant insert here. When I loop the group (A compares from ID_A1 to ID_C3), every 95% to 96% will group into group A, and the number of group = 1, and when I loop the group (B compares from ID_A1 to ID_C3), every 95% to 96% will group into group B, and the number of group will be +1. The result that I want is showing the total number of groups in the range of 95% to 96%.

I would like to add something which is when in the range of 95.0% to 96.0%, IF there are 95.5% and 95.6%, how to group them as individual group?

The example output would be like:

```
"In the range of 95% to 96%, there is 1 group of 95.5% and 1 group of 95.6%"
"Total number of groups: ... "
```

PS: I need to use the number of groups to plot a graph

Comment: I can't seem to grasp what you're trying to ask... _" I want it to be grouped like in a range of 95% to 96% with an increment 0.1, depends on how user want to input the range."_

Comment: the codes above will give you the results(similarities) in percentage (%), i would like to set a range which is 95% to 96% with an increment of 0.1, which is from 95.0, 95.1, 95.2 until 96.0%. From the results(similarities), if there are percentages from group A match the condition, then number of group +1. If no then continue to the next group

Comment: @danny Could you add the actual desired output for your data to the question?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Done

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do.  What is stopping you from doing it?  When you try, what happens?

Comment: When I give it a try, I'm always stuck at not knowing all the syntax, keep on failing to get the result i want and lots of errors even though i have the logic in my mind, I'm sure that I'm lack of practice. So it would be nice if I can learn codes here and enhance my programming knowledge.